# After setContentView element SurfaceView draw under StreetViewPanoramaView

Tags: android, surfaceview, setcontentview

First time here.
I create application with StreetView. Want draw markers on top Street View panoramas.

Switch between layouts with setContentView(). On layout with element "StreetViewPanoramaView extends FrameLayout" (com.google.android.gms.maps) i have element "StreetOverlayView extends SurfaceView". 
With "Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();" i draw bitmap on SurfaceView.

look:
SurfaceView draw bitmap
StreetView

after setContentView all time look like:
StreetView
SurfaceView draw bitmap

I tried different options:
1) first setContentView(layout with StreetViewPanoramaView) and bitmap draw on top and look good. 
After i setContentView(another layout) and again setContentView(layout with StreetViewPanoramaView) - bitmap NOT draw : ( on top - only under StreetViewPanoramaView.

2) first setContentView(another layout) and after setContentView(layout with StreetViewPanoramaView) - bitmap NOT draw : ( on top.

I tried "bringChildToFront" with elements in layout - not work.

How can i return SurfaceView with canvas draw on top ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solution:
Put "StreetOverlayView extends SurfaceView" element in new FrameLayout and after setContentView i remove my element from this FrameLayout and add again.

```
    frame1.removeView(  markerView  );
    frame1.addView   (  markerView  );
```